# how can i display data from xml file after compare it with some variable?

Tags: php, xml

i have some data in xml file agent.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<agents>
    <agent>
    <image> img/sara.jpg</image>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Tommy Jenkin</name>
    <company>CJenkins Insurance</company>
    <street>Insurance150 S State Stree</street>
    <city>Linkend</city>
    <phone>(773) 561-4331</phone>
    </agent>
    <agent>
    <image> img/primary-nav-logo.png</image>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>saka</name>
    <company>LIC Insurance</company>
    <street>Insurance150 S State Stree</street>
    <city>Linkend</city>
    <phone>(773) 561-4331</phone>
    </agent>
</agents>
```

Now i have one variable called id in php like below

```
$id = 1
```

Now i am displaying this xml data with following code

```
 <?php
                $xml = simplexml_load_file("agent.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
                foreach($xml as $agent){
                function processXML($node){
                    foreach($node->children() as $agent => $data){
                        $agent= trim($agent);   
                        if($agent=='image')
                        {
                            echo '<div><img src="'.$data.'" ></div>';
                            echo '<div>';
                            echo '</div>';
                        }
                        elseif($agent=='id')
                        {
                             echo '<div class = "Left">';
                             echo '<input type = "button" name="Agent" id = "'.$data.'" class = "subs-btn" value = "Select this Agent" OnClick = Selected(this.id);>';
                             echo '</div>';
                             echo '<br/>';
                             echo '<br/>';  
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo '<div class = "inline1">';
                            echo $data;
                            echo '</div>';
                            echo '<br/>';

                        }
                            processXML($data);
                        }           

                    }  
                processXML($xml);
                }
            ?>
```

But need a data from xml file having id = 1 
so how can i compare it and display it
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `xpath` to select the `<agent>` with the desired `<id>`:

```
$agent = $xml->xpath("/agents/agent[id='1']");

if (isset($agent[0])) $agent = $agent[0]; else $agent = NULL;
echo $agent->name;
```

Comment: Can you please tell me in my code where and how can i use it because i had try your code but it will get blank page

Comment: @SanjayRathod Sorry, I can't write or review your code. SO is for getting ansers to specific questions, not for code review. Why not try for yourself? If specific questions come up, feel free to write a question.